# App crashes on smaller devices because of actionbar

Tags: android

My application gets crashed when I run my app on small device.....i am using action bar and I am using appcompat_v7_2 lib...it is working fine in all devices except smaller ones 320x240...
I am getting this error n i have searched a lot but nothing has helped me...

```
03-31 06:42:32.228: E/AndroidRuntime(1000): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.shopping.online/com.shopping.online.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Binary XML file line #149: You must supply a layout_width attribute.
03-31 06:42:32.228: E/AndroidRuntime(1000):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
03-31 06:42:32.228: E/AndroidRuntime(1000):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
03-31 06:42:32.228: E/AndroidRuntime(1000):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
03-31 06:42:32.228: E/AndroidRuntime(1000):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
03-31 06:42:32.228: E/AndroidRuntime(1000):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-31 06:42:32.228: E/AndroidRuntime(1000):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-31 06:42:32.228: E/AndroidRuntime(1000):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
03-31 06:42:32.228: E/AndroidRuntime(1000):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-31 06:42:32.228: E/AndroidRuntime(1000):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
03-31 06:42:32.228: E/AndroidRuntime(1000):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
03-31 06:42:32.228: E/AndroidRuntime(1000):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
03-31 06:42:32.228: E/AndroidRuntime(1000):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-31 06:42:32.228: E/AndroidRuntime(1000): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Binary XML file line #149: You must supply a layout_width attribute.
03-31 06:42:32.228: E/AndroidRuntime(1000):     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getLayoutDimension(TypedArray.java:491)
03-31 06:42:32.228: E/AndroidRuntime(1000):     at android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams.setBaseAttributes(ViewGroup.java:5823)
03-31 06:42:32.228: E/AndroidRuntime(1000):     at android.view.ViewGroup$MarginLayoutParams.<init>(ViewGroup.java:5992)
03-31 06:42:32.228: E/AndroidRuntime(1000):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams.<init>(RelativeLayout.java:1246)
03-31 06:42:32.228: E/AndroidRuntime(1000):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.generateLayoutParams(RelativeLayout.java:1083)
03-31 06:42:32.228: E/AndroidRuntime(1000):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.generateLayoutParams(RelativeLayout.java:84)
03-31 06:42:32.228: E/AndroidRuntime(1000):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:757)
03-31 06:42:32.228: E/AndroidRuntime(1000):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
03-31 06:42:32.228: E/AndroidRuntime(1000):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
03-31 06:42:32.228: E/AndroidRuntime(1000):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
03-31 06:42:32.228: E/AndroidRuntime(1000):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
03-31 06:42:32.228: E/AndroidRuntime(1000):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
03-31 06:42:32.228: E/AndroidRuntime(1000):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
03-31 06:42:32.228: E/AndroidRuntime(1000):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
03-31 06:42:32.228: E/AndroidRuntime(1000):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
03-31 06:42:32.228: E/AndroidRuntime(1000):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:267)
03-31 06:42:32.228: E/AndroidRuntime(1000):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1895)
03-31 06:42:32.228: E/AndroidRuntime(1000):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.superSetContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:216)
03-31 06:42:32.228: E/AndroidRuntime(1000):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:110)
03-31 06:42:32.228: E/AndroidRuntime(1000):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:76)
03-31 06:42:32.228: E/AndroidRuntime(1000):     at com.shopping.online.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:94)
03-31 06:42:32.228: E/AndroidRuntime(1000):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
03-31 06:42:32.228: E/AndroidRuntime(1000):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
03-31 06:42:32.228: E/AndroidRuntime(1000):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
03-31 06:42:32.228: E/AndroidRuntime(1000):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: In some of your layouts you have missed to add the layout_width attribute.

Comment: the problem  is not in xml...i guess it has to do with library bcoz this lib is not supported in small devices

Comment: Check XML file for MainActivity line no 149 you missed Layout Width. ActionBar works perfectly on all devices

Comment: It is clearly state in your log cat `java.lang.RuntimeException: Binary XML file line #149: You must supply a layout_width attribute.` @SonalAsija

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is only a wild guess, but I had a similar problem which turned out to be a bug in certain Samsung devices with Android 4.1 or 4.2 which internally have a class that's named the same than one in the support library.

I know it sounds weird, but your exception reminds me of the one I got from that.

So are you sure it has to do with the display size or could it be that your small devices are Samsung devices?

**Edit:**

The description of the samsung bug and fixes can be [found here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=78377). But the execption looks rather different, so I'm even less sure than before.

Comment: Try to set up a small emulator device and check if your app runs there? If it does, chances are that's the Samsung bug. I'll see if I find what I did against it. Was something with the proguard settings to rename or not rename this or that class...

Comment: i tried to run this on small emulator but its still crashing...i didnt made any changes in proguard settings